# AWS RDS MySQL Unexpected Restart

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, innodb, rds

Our t3.micro RDS database somehow got restarted periodically without any interaction, graph from cloudwatch shown belom: https://snipboard.io/hHWmAv.jpg

MySQL error log only showing the crash, without telling the reason behind.

```
2019-09-10T16:17:49.424529Z 0 [Note] Giving 24 client threads a chance to die gracefully
2019-09-10T16:17:49.426015Z 0 [Note] Shutting down slave threads
2019-09-10T16:19:02.043381Z 0 [Warning] 'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER' sql mode was not set.
2019-09-10T16:19:02.044006Z 0 [Warning] Insecure configuration for --secure-file-priv: Location is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
2019-09-10T16:19:02.044772Z 0 [Note] /rdsdbbin/mysql/bin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.16-log) starting as process 3697 ...
2019-09-10T16:19:02.066197Z 0 [Warning] Although a path was specified for the --slow-query-log-file option, log tables are used. To enable logging to files use the --log-output=file option.
2019-09-10T16:19:02.078166Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2019-09-10T16:19:02.078194Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2019-09-10T16:19:02.078197Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2019-09-10T16:19:02.078201Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2019-09-10T16:19:02.078204Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2019-09-10T16:19:02.078207Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2019-09-10T16:19:02.080206Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2019-09-10T16:19:02.083495Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2019-09-10T16:19:02.085725Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 384M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2019-09-10T16:19:02.114854Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2019-09-10T16:19:02.119186Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2019-09-10T16:19:02.140345Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2019-09-10T16:19:02.146556Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 4435206383
2019-09-10T16:19:02.146572Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 4435206392
2019-09-10T16:19:02.148891Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 4435206392
2019-09-10T16:19:02.148903Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2019-09-10T16:19:02.148907Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2019-09-10T16:19:02.781069Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Last MySQL binlog file position 0 2011, file name mysql-bin-changelog.208136
2019-09-10T16:19:03.345253Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2019-09-10T16:19:03.345270Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2019-09-10T16:19:03.345301Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file '/rdsdbdata/db/innodb/ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2019-09-10T16:19:03.420337Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File '/rdsdbdata/db/innodb/ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2019-09-10T16:19:03.421137Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2019-09-10T16:19:03.421148Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2019-09-10T16:19:03.421347Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2019-09-10T16:19:03.471811Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.16 started; log sequence number 4435206392
2019-09-10T16:19:03.472007Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /rdsdbdata/db/innodb/ib_buffer_pool
2019-09-10T16:19:03.473460Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2019-09-10T16:19:03.483168Z 0 [Note] Recovering after a crash using /rdsdbdata/log/binlog/mysql-bin-changelog
2019-09-10T16:19:03.483203Z 0 [Note] Starting crash recovery...
2019-09-10T16:19:03.483253Z 0 [Note] Crash recovery finished.
```

Is there a way to prevent this? Or is there anymore logs that I can dig through? I've asked similar question to aws forum, sadly with no response https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=915571#915571

Comment: This question has nothing to do with programming, therefore it is off topic here at SO. There is a dba sister site of SO specifically created for database administrators.

Comment: @samuel-adam The sixth line of the error log has warned you there will not be any log files. Corrective action; in your AWS Performance group for log_output=FILE for log to named files.  AWS does not allow BOTH TABLE and FILE.